# Yoga and Vaishnava Sampradaya

Tags: vaishnavism, yoga, yoga-sutras, yoga-vashishtha

I am wondering if I could be a Vaishnava and go through Yoga philosophy versus Vedanta it's more catered to my style of learning and worshiping the supreme and seeing my relationship with him. I already read Bhagavad Gita and am moving on to Yoga Sutras and then to Yoga Vashista and Yoga Yajnavalakaya. Is there anything else I need to know before continuing with this path.

Comment: Most of the Vaishnava sampradayas deny the existence of Yoga in the form of Yoga Vasistha, Patanjali or Yajnavalkya, they don't even subscribe to their principles. They don't acknowledge - kaivalya samadhi either, despite its existence and practice.

Comment: Related --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14969