# Where is the Manipura Chakra located?

Tags: yoga, body, chakras

I read in different sources about different locations of the manipura chakra. Two finger-width under the navel, secondly the navel and thirdly the solar plexus with is two or three finger width above the navel. Do different traditions locate it differently or how does the term work?

Comment: `http://www.tantra-kundalini.com/manipura.htm` and also please check `https://mychakras.wordpress.com/2008/05/27/third-chakra-navel-chakra-manipura-chakra/`

Comment: You maybe interested in my answer here ... http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/reference-to-the-7-chakras-in-hinduism/13742#13742

Comment: The chakras, according to Ramakrishna Paramahamsa and Swami Vivekananda are not actually located in the physical body. Yogic concepts can be correlated with the anatomical, but the charkras do not exist in an ordinary person, but exist in the subtle planes and are only made viable when the sushumna has opened. The manipura corresponds with the coeliac or solar plexus.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda : Given that the solar plexus is in human located at a different place than the navel, why do people like Tezz say that it corresponds to the navel?

Comment: Read Tezz's answer carefully. It says specifically subtle body, not gross body. This is a tremendous misunderstanding among Westerners who identify themselves with the gross body only and think that the chakras are in the gross body and are active. They are not in the gross body and neither are they active until the sushumna has opened. It is no small thing to get the sushumna to open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Manipura is present in Solar Region. It is also known as Nabhi Chakra. Nabhi in Sanskrit means Navel. But as the location of Chakra is in backbone region of subtle body, hence Manipura Chakra is present just at back side of Navel in the region of backbone (in the subtle body).

But the entire Navel region is in the range of Manipura Chakra.

**Srimad Bhagvatam** also calls the Manipura Chakra by the name Navel Chakra.

> कृत्वा समानावनिलौ जितासना सोदानमुत्थात्य च **नाभिचक्रतः** । 
>   Then she carried the life air upwards and placed it in the position of equilibrium near the Nabhi Chakra/ Navel Chakra [Manipura Chakra.] (S.B. 4.4.25)

Guru Gorakhnath who is incarnation of Lord Shiva also calls Chakra present in Navel region is called Manipura in Goraksha Shataka:

> तं नाभिमण्डलं चक्र प्रोच्यते मणिपुरकम् ।
>   Chakra present in Navel region is called Manipura.

**Devi Bhagvtam** in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk07ch35.htm) talks about Nadi and Chakra in detail

> There are the 350,000 nâdis in this body of man; of these, the principal are ten. Out of the ten again, the three are most prominent. The foremost and first of these three is Susumnâ, of the nature of the Moon, Sun, and Fire, situated in the centre of the spinal cord (it extends from the sacral plexus below to the Brahmaradhra in the head at the top where it looks like a blown Dhustûra flower). On the left of this Susumnâ is the Idâ Nâdî, white and looking like Moon; this Nâdî is of the nature of Force, nectar-like. On the right side of the Susumnâ is the Pingalâ Nâdî of the nature of a male; it represents the Sun. **The Susumnâ comprises the nature of the all the Tejas (fires) and it represents Fire.** 
>  
>   31-41. **The inmost of Susumnâ is Vichtrâ or Chitrinî Bhûlingam nâdî (of the form of a cobweb) in the middle of which resides the Ichchâ (will), Jñâna (knowledge) and Kriyâ (action) S'aktîs, and resplendent like the Millions of Suns.** Above Him is situated Hrîm, the Mâyâ Vîja Harâtmâ with "Ha" and Chandravindu repesenting the Sound (Nâda). Above this is the Flame, Kula Kundalinî (the Serpent Fire) of a red colour, and as it were, intoxicated. Outside Her is the Âdhâra Lotus of a yellow colour having a dimension of four digits and Comprising the four letters "va", "s'a", "sa", and "sa". The Yogis meditate on this. In its centre is the hexagonal space (Pîtham). This is called the Mûlâdhâra for it is the base and it supports all the six lotuses. Above it is the Svâdhisthâna Chakra, fiery and emitting lustre like diamond and with six petals representing the six letters "ba", "bha", "ma", "ya", "ra", "la". The word "Sva" means "Param Lingam" (superior Male Symbol). Therefore the sages call this "Svâdhisthân Chakram. **Above it is situated the "Manipura Chakram" of the colour of lightning in clouds and very fiery; it comprises the ten Petals, comprising the 10 letters da, dha, na, ta, tha, da, dha, na, pa, pha. The lotus resembles a full blown pearl; hence it is "Manipadma." Visnu dwells here. Meditation here leads to the sight of Visnu.**

Comment: Can you be more precise what you mean with the navel region? Where are the boundaries of it?

Comment: @Christian whole Navel region is boundary of Manipura... but the place through which Kundalini pass through Manipura is through Sushumna Nadi which is present in subtle region of backbone...ie. just opposite to navel...

Comment: I don't know what "whole Navel region" is supposed to mean. How many centimeters (or finger-widths) above the navel does the "whole Navel region" start. Does it go up to the [solar plexus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celiac_plexus)?

Comment: If you want to just energize Manipura Chakra and not for Kundalini Awakening then you can just meditate on whole Navel region... if you want Kundalini Awakening you can start from Muladhara which is in Perinium region... then you will yourself know where the other Chakras are when Kundalini ascends from Muladhara...

Comment: @Christian first you should know basics of arrangement of Chakra in body to know it... if you want to discuss you can come here... http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/discussion-on-vedanta-and-philosophy

Comment: Are you saying that were the chakra's are located is not part of the basics of arrangement of the Chakra's? That I need to know other basics before you can tell me what you mean navel region and the boundaries of the navel region?

Answer (score 8):

Manipura Chakra is exactly located at *Nabhi* (Navel) but in Subtle body along the Spinal cord. All Chakras are located in Straight line (in Subtle body).

[Om Swami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Swami) describes method to identify seven Chakras in body in his book [Kundalini: An untold story](http://www.amazon.in/Kundalini-untold-story-Om-Swami/dp/8184958625).

> Here is how to identify the location of chakras in your body. Use your
>   right hand if you are right-handed and left hand if you are
>   left-handed.
>
> 1. **Place the little finger of your hand on the navel. Your navel is the solar plexus or the manipura chakra.**
> 2. Stretch your hand fully upwards and see where the tip of the thumb touches. This is your heart plexus or the anahata chakra.
> 3. Place your little finger exactly where your thumb touched on the heart plexus and stretch your hand fully once again to see where the
>      thumb touches now. This is your throat plexus or the vishuddhi chakra.
> 4. Once again, put your little finger exactly where your thumb was and move one full hand-measure up. Your thumb is now touching your
>      brow plexus or the agya chakra.
> 5. Place your little finger where you just found your brow chakra and stretch your hand fully again. Your thumb will be now touching your
>      crown chakra or Sahasrara.
> 6. Go back to the navel. Put your thumb on your navel, stretch your hand and go one full hand measure down. Your little finger is now
>      touching your sacral plexus or svadhishthana chakra.
> 7. Place your thumb where your little finger just was and stretch your hand fully downwards one more time. Your little finger is now
>      touching your root plexus or muladhara chakra.
>
> Make sure to take your hand measure from the tip of your little finger
>   to the tip of your thumb. Just like if you stretch your arms, the
>   distance from the tip of one middle finger to the other is same as the
>   height of your body, the distance between one chakra and the other is
>   exactly one hand. Only your hand can accurately pinpoint the location
>   of your chakras.

Comment: The words navel and solar plexus as used in the English language refer to different points. A source that says that the two are the same is either plain wrong or means something different than what the words usually mean in English.

Comment: @Christian Do you want center of Manipura Chakra and radius and its location relative to solar plexus? Manipura Chakra is located in Navel Region.

Comment: The sentence "Your navel is the solar plexus" is plainly wrong given the meaning of those words in English. It's factually as sensible as saying that your nose is located where the mouth is. Those are two different points. 
I don't know what's meant with the naval region. The naval + a 5 cm radius? Something else?