# Does Hindu scripture say anything about Third Eye visions?

Tags: ganesha, symbolism, meditation, dream

Recently, while meditating, I had a vision of Lord Ganesha. The vision came to my 3<sup>rd</sup> Eye.

The vision was of an Elephant, with its Trunk pointed down, but swaying back and forward, almost in a dancing rhythm. The Trunk had Fractals of other Trunks in it, and in those were more Fractal-ed trunks.

I have a great deal of interest in Hinduism, however I did not worship Ganesha, or speak to him previous to this vision.

From my subsequent research, I have learned that the Poses, and the orientation of Lord Ganesha's trunk are important.

Does this mean anything? Does any Hindu scripture say anything about such visions?

Comment: This might indicate some energy movements in the Muladhara Chakra as Ganesha is related to Muladhara Chakra.

Comment: You're welcome.. btw if you are interested in chakra concepts you can see my [answer here.](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/reference-to-the-7-chakras-in-hinduism/13742#13742)

Comment: How is this opinion-based? Someone knowledgeable in yoga and kundalini can give a correct answer. Third eye visions are not open to interpretations and hence are not opinion-based.

Comment: Should I delete the Question?

Comment: Why delete? NO NEED.. There will be an answer to your question. All you should do is wait for some time. @moonstar2001 Please vote to reopen if you find this question helpful.

Comment: Even third eye visions are open to interpretation because not everyone witnesses same thing there. you can also discuss this topic in chat room as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what Sri Ramakrishna says:

> The fourth plane of the mind is at the heart. When the mind dwells
>   there, one has the first glimpse of spiritual consciousness. One sees
>   light all around. Such a man, perceiving the divine light, becomes
>   speechless with wonder and says: 'Ah! What is this? What is this? His
>   mind does not go downward to the object of the world.
>
> The fifth plane of the mind is the throat. When the mind reaches this,
>   the aspirant becomes free from all ignorance and illusion. He does not
>   enjoy talking or hearing anything but God. If people talk about
>   worldly things, he leaves the place at once.
>
> **The sixth plane is at the forehead. When the mind reaches it, the
>   aspirant sees the form of God day and night. But even then a little
>   trace of ego remains. At the sight of that incomparable beauty of
>   God's form, one becomes intoxicated and rushes forth to touch and
>   embrace it. But one doesn't succeed. It is like the light inside a
>   lantern. One feels as if one could touch the light, but one cannot on
>   account of the plane of glass.**
>
> In the top of the head is the seventh plane. When the mind rises
>   there, one goes into samadhi. Then the Brahmajnani directly perceives
>   Brahman,. But in that state his body does not last many days. He
>   remains unconscious of the outer world. If milk is poured into his
>   mouth, it runs out. Dwelling on this plane of consciousness, he gives
>   up his body in twenty-one days.

The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna October 28, 1882

Answer (score 0):

**Ajna Charkra** also called Third eye (an "intra" organ) is located in your brow center. **Ajna Charkra** is the seat of our will. And our will is our spiritual umbilical cord, our connection to the cosmos.

> **tayāpūryāśu mūrdhāntaṃ bhaṅaktavā  bhrūkṣepasetunā ।**
>
> **nirvikalpaṃ manaḥ kṛtvā sarvordhve sarvagodgamaḥ ॥ 31 ॥**
>
> *Shiva Sutras, sutra 31, dhāraṇa 8*

***Translation:*** Let form be filled with essence of life-breath to the crown of head. Cross the life-breath by penetrating with one-pointed attention at the bridge-like center of the eyebrows (the third eye). Let mind be beyond the movement of thoughts [nirvikalpam manah]. In that all-rising supreme state (of Shiva), showers the light (vision) of all-pervadingness.

Different Hindu scriptures might word it differently but the meaning/essence would be the same. Having given the scriptural references to the 3rd eye the following scenarios are possible.

1. You had a "Darshan" of Lord Ganesha, if that is the case then when you open your eyes you will see the "action replay" of the whole vision in the same detail
2. You don't have had to worship Lord Ganesha for his "Darshan" to happen, just the will of an awakened 3rd eye is enough.
3. Even if your 3rd eye is not awakened its possible to have "Darshan". The purpose and interpretations can be very easily found out by 3rd eye awakened yogis esp those who can entangle with Lord KalaBhairava

References:

1. "Third Eye Power: The Ability to Will" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtqH1A11Sys
2. "7 Extraordinary Powers Associated With Eyes" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbqXC1RnIAQ
3. "Shaktis of third eye" http://yogashaktis.innerawakening.org/powers-third-eye/
4. "Manifesting Shaktis Appendix" http://books.nithyanandatimes.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2016/12/Manifesting-Shaktis-Appendix.pdf

PS: I kept the answer short to conform to guidelines