# What are the letter of alphabets (varnas) associated with each of the Seven Chakras?

Tags: scripture, agamas, tantra, chakras

Body consists of mainly seven chakras as I [discuss here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/reference-to-the-7-chakras-in-hinduism/13742#13742) In the Netra Tantra book I have; in the introductory preface part it is written:

> Muladhara, Swadhisthana, Manipura, Anahat, Shakini and Ajna these six chakra contains lotus petals from 'अ' / 'A' to 'क्ष' / 'Ksha' for 50 letters of alphabet made yantra. **Muladhara etc.. from this order contains petal numbers in the order 4, 6, 10, 12, 16 and 2. ie. Muladhara contains 4 and Ajna contains 2 letters.** Or kundalini which is also called Chidagni or Chaitanya (Consciousness).....

This means that each petal consists separate letters (varnas) and total is 4 + 6 + 10 +12 + 16 +2 = 50 which is formed like a Yantra in the body.

What are the letters associated with each Chakra which forms this Yantra? I'm mainly wanting answers from Agamas/Tantras.

Comment: Have you checked Shiva Swarodaya?

Comment: @Pandya No, I do not have it...

Comment: So.this netra tantra is a KS text isnt it ?

Comment: @Rakesh yes, it is...

Answer (score 7):

chakras have various number of petals which reflect their current. The life current in chakra is linked to its petals too. They are present in astral body.

**moolAdhAra chakra** - four petals - व श स ष (golden colored letters on red petals)

**swAdhishthana chakra** - six petals - ब भ म य र ल (with bindu, white lightning color)

**maNipUra chakra**- ten petals - ड ढ ण त थ द ध न प फ (with chandra bindu, color of blue lotus)

**anAhata chakra** - twelve petals - क  ख   ग   घ   ङ च छ   ज झ ञ ट ठ (color of vermilion)

**Vishuddhi chakra**- sixteen petals - अ आ इ ई उ ऊ ऋ ॠ ऌ ॡ ए ऐ ओ औ  अं अः (red color letters)

**ajna chakra** - two petals - ह क्ष (white colored)

**sahasrAra chakra** - thousand (many) petals- all the 50 varNa mAlA  from अ - क्ष  (white colored )

Reference

***ShaT chakra nirupaNam***

Comment: Is it from Shat Chakra Nirupanam of Guru Gorakhnath?..

Comment: @Tezz no its on archive.org. there is hindi translation also but i am not finding link. Plus its also elaborated in. Sir John woodrofe books

Comment: Shatchakranirupanam is a Bengali Tantrik work. Arthur Avalon also has a book on it.

Comment: Yes it's Sanskrit but author is Bengali. @RakeshJoshi Like Tantra Sara, Shaktananda Tarangini etc.