# Which tantric books illustrate Chakras, nadis, deities in body of purusha?

Tags: yoga, tantra

Which tantric books contain traditional detailed illustrations of Chakras, nadis, as well as deities (both vedic 33, puranic including numerous various names/Manifestations of deities)  located on/in the body of purusha(including on ears, palms) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the letter of alphabets (varnas) associated with each of the Seven Chakras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22567/what-are-the-letter-of-alphabets-varnas-associated-with-each-of-the-seven-chak)

Answer (score 3):

The Kundalini and six chakra related concepts and sadhanas are present in many tantras. [Shat-Chakra-Nirupana](https://www.amazon.in/Serpent-Power-Shat-Chakra-Nirupana-Paduka-Panchaka/dp/8178223783), Swatantra-Tantra and Kankala-malini-Tantra discuss the topics in detail. Tantra is a unique blend of Advaita-Darshana and Yoga-Darshana.

The [Kankala-Malini-Tantra](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/kankal-malini-tantra-HAA392/) describes the deities like Kamini, Dakini, Rakini, Lakini,Kakini,Hakini, etc at different padmas. It also discusses the samadhi state of the sadhaka (Purusha).

[Sarada-Tilaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarada_Tilaka) also has the sadhana of shakchakraveda in detail.

Upendrakumar Das has quoted all the relevant slokas with bengali translations in Vol 2 of his 'Shastramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana' (chapter 18).

Comment: Could not find any link for Swatantra Tantram , for all others I hv added the links

Comment: @Rickross the question has been changed! Do you know its answer?

Comment: I am not sure about the Q .. on ears and palm which chakras exist? None

Comment: @Rickross i have never heard of any. These were not there in the original Q i think

Comment: Yes so u are answering the original version of the Q and that's ok

Comment: Not Chakras, but deities(like accupuressure points/marma), I.e: I have read somewhere that agni resides on right ear.

Comment: What about nadis, is there any book that describes/ and illustrates locations of all main, sub important nadis?

Comment: @Aoi.T_015 a beautiful diagram by Yogiraj Shyamacharan Lahiri is given in Bhupendranath Sanyal's bengali commentary of Gita.Thats really fascinating.But most probably the book has not been translated to english.