# What is the physical location of the chakras?

Tags: yoga, tantra, chakras

Where exactly are the chakras located ?

If one is to visualise and meditate on a chakra, where in the spine are the chakras ?

If looking at the spine's 3-D image, are the chakras located immediately behind the skin (of our backs), in the middle of the spine ? 
Or where ?

Edit : I am not exactly interested in the location of the chakra on the vertebrae but where on the vertebrae. Which dimension/side. The linked question does not answer my question as I am interested to know where in the vertebrae are the chakras.

Comment: I don't think you are able to see Chakras physically, you can only see them with yogic vision.

Comment: @Tezz. I always thought chakras are just locations where a lot of nerves connected. Sort of nerve plexus.  I think what I am trying to ask it, if I have to meditate in my Manipura Chakra, then from my naval to the skin on my back- between these two points, where should I visualise the chakra to be ? Just behind the skin on my belly (behind naval) or at the backside/ on the spine ?

Comment: this has been asked in previous questions. The chakras have a corresponding location in the fine body that are approximately in line with the different locations in the spine, but they exist in the fine body, they do not exist in the physical body. You cannot physically touch or influence them through physical matter.

Comment: see my answer here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body/6787#6787

Comment: Already having answer here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/reference-to-the-7-chakras-in-hinduism

Comment: As rightly said by  @Swami Vishwananda , the position is in the spine at corresponding location. e.g. for "Manipur chakra", consider a horizontal line penetrating from naval and entering the spinal cord. Where it penetrates the spine, it is that location.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I read through your answer (pretty heavy reading). Though I didn't go through the reference links, it isn't clear to me where you talk about the location of the actual chakras ?

Comment: @Vineet Where did you read this information off ? I have read the linked answer by Swami Vishwananda but dont see this mentioned any where

Comment: If the questions are same, they will be closed as duplicates because the answers will be repeated again. To avoid repetition, we close as duplicates.