# Which scripture talks about chakras (energy centers) present in human?

Tags: scripture, mantras, chakras, kundalini

We have been knowing that there are colors and mantra (or sound) associated with each chakras (energy centers) in subtle human body. Which scripture mentions about it? I am interested in the oldest source of that chakra-color association.

(Just for information, the reason I am interested is because the colors from muladhara to sahasrara is in increasing order of frequency of colors. Isn't it weird if it had been assigned before modern science found about the frequency stuffs? And maybe there's similar thing with the sound as well!!)

Comment: See this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13742/4732

Answer (score 1):

Chakras are described in Tantrik Yoga Shasthra. Each chakra has its own adhi devata, yantra and characteristics. By meditating the adhi devata of the chakra will give us success to raise the kundali power towards the chakra. Chakra(Energy Center) starts from Mooladhara and ends at Sahasahara(Parabhamham - Eternal and Pure state).

Soundharyalahari(A masterpiece by Adhishankaracharya) explains well about Chakras. Each sloka has its own yantra. On meditating this, one will attain success in materialistic and spiritual life by The Goddess Lalitha Tripurasundari's anugraha.

It is closed related to Shri Yantra - Mother of all yantras. It describes how to raise kundalini between energy levels(Chakras). It has nava avarnas. First two avarna represents devata which govern the materialistic world. After passing this, soul realizes the nature of atman. By practising meditations upon the particular avarna will help us to pass through the energy level. Lalitha Tripurasundari is ruling the Sahasrara Chakra in the Bindhu of the yantra.

Soundharyalahari - 35th Verse

मनस्त्वम्  व्योमस्त्वम्  मरुदसि   मरुत्  सारथिरसि

त्वमापस्त्वम् भूमि: त्वयि  परिणतायाम् नहि परं

त्वमेव स्वात्मानं  परिणमयितुं विश्ववपूषा

चिदानन्दाकारं शिवयुवतिभावेना बिभृषे  ॥  ३५

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saundarya_Lahari)

Besides Color, Each Chakra is associated with Swaram(note with a specific frequency). Sapta swara represents Sapta Chakras.

Shadjamam(Sa)   - Mooladharam,
Rishabham(Ri)   - Swadhistanam,
Gandharam(Ga)   - Manibhooragam,
Madhyamam(Ma)   - Vishuddhi,
Panchamam(Pa)   - Anahadham,
Dhaivadham(Dha) - Aagna,
Nishadham(Ni)   - Sahasrara.