# Are there any ragas/musical instruments associated with each chakras/energy centres?

Tags: mantras, spirituality, sadhana, chakras

I am interested in knowing and understanding if there are any Indian classical ragas/ musical instrument associated with the chakras/energy centres? Reason am asking is coz we have seed syllables/beej mantras for each chakras and usually they are chanted in order to activate the respective chakras/energy centre, similarly there must be a raga/musical instrument that does the same thing?

Comment: The question posed seems to have an excellent answer in a question with albeit different wordings: [Reference to the 7 chakras in Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13742/17833)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference to the 7 chakras in Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/reference-to-the-7-chakras-in-hinduism)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am already aware of that. Thanks though .@Vivikta

Comment: @Just_Do_It. You may find this link interesting
https://www.shankarramani.com/music-and-chakras.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something relevant to my question here : [Instruments and Chakras](https://www.swamipurnachaitanya.com/how-different-musical-instruments-affect-the-7-chakras/)

**Drums** are connected to the **Muladhara** chakra, and **big pipes or trumpets** (wind instruments) affect the **Swadhisthana** chakra. The third chakra **Manipura**  is stimulated by **string instruments** played through friction like the violin and the heart chakra **Anahata** resonates with **plucked string instruments** like guitar and piano. The sound of **flute** stimulates the throat chakra **Vishuddhi**  and **small bells** are connected to the **Ajña** chakra between the eyebrows. The sound of the blowing of the Shankha or conch finally stimulates the Sahasrara or crown chakra.

This phenomenon was already known to the sages in the ancient Vedic times and is also revealed in the scriptures dealing with the architecture of temples. Large temples used to have seven big gateways that lead one to the main deity. Each consecutive gate having different instruments to stimulate the 7 chakras and direct the energy upwards to the top of the head where bliss is experienced. The outermost gate would have large drums, the next large trumpets, and so on.

To me it makes sense, so posted as an answer.